# SQL/Mysql query available dates and times in database

Tags: mysql, sql, date, laravel-5, calendar

I need some help querying my calendar/dates table

Scenario: I have a "calendar" table with dates and times (see below), users will set their available dates, usually day by day with available time slots for each day. So my table looks like this:

```
+------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
| ID   | user_id    | start_date          | end_date            | 
+------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
|    1 |          1 | 2016-09-01 08:00:00 | 2016-09-01 16:00:00 | 
|    2 |          1 | 2016-09-03 00:00:00 | 2016-09-03 23:59:59 | 
|    3 |          1 | 2016-09-04 00:00:00 | 2016-09-04 16:00:00 | 
|    4 |          1 | 2016-09-05 08:00:00 | 2016-09-05 16:00:00 | 
|    5 |          2 | 2016-09-05 08:00:00 | 2016-09-05 16:00:00 | 
|    6 |          2 | 2016-09-07 08:00:00 | 2016-09-07 16:00:00 | 
|    7 |          2 | 2016-09-08 08:00:00 | 2016-09-08 16:00:00 | 
|    8 |          2 | 2016-09-08 18:00:00 | 2016-09-08 22:00:00 |
+------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

We have 2 users here so I want the following:

- If I search for start_date = 2016-09-05 08:00:00 and end_date = 2016-09-05 16:00:00 it should return user 1 and 2. Since both of them has an entry with these dates. Same goes as well if start_date = 2016-09-05 09:00:00 and end_date = 2016-09-05 15:00:00, this should as well return both users since the time im searching for is between the time slots as shown in the example.
- Second scenario is a little bit more tricky, If user search for start_date = 2016-09-03 08:00:00 and end_date = 2016-09-04 16:00:00 i want the query to check the following:

  - see if the user is available each day at these times.
  - so in this case, is the user available on 2016-09-03 between 08:00:00 and 16:00:00 and as well on 2016-09-04 between 08:00:00 and 16:00:00.
  - In the example over this should return user 1.

Im open for suggestion on re-designed my schema if needed.

Hope some can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PFRW57177)** include some aditional code comment, and show how the query evolve . Also I add another row for `user_id = 2` to show how only match one of the two days in the range.

```
SELECT U.`user_id`
FROM (
        select a.selectDate,
               CONCAT(a.selectDate, ' ', time(@s_date)) as start_time,
               CONCAT(a.selectDate, ' ', time(@s_date)) as end_time
        from (
            select '1900-01-01' + INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) DAY as selectDate
            from       (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
            cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
            cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
            cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
            cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as e
        ) a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s_date := '2016-09-03 08:00:00', @e_date := '2016-09-04 16:00:00') par
        -- CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s_date := '2016-09-05 08:00:00', @e_date := '2016-09-05 16:00:00') par
        -- CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s_date := '2016-09-05 09:00:00', @e_date := '2016-09-05 15:00:00') par
        WHERE selectDate BETWEEN date(@s_date) 
                             AND date(@e_date)
     ) D
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM Table1) U
LEFT  JOIN Table1 T
        ON U.`user_id` = T.`user_id`
       AND D.start_time <= T.`end_date`
       AND D.end_time   >= T.`start_date`
GROUP BY U.`user_id`
HAVING COUNT(U.`user_id`) = COUNT(T.`user_id`);
```

**OUTPUT**

- Step 1: create a list of dates, in this case 273 years
- Step 2: select all dates between the range define in the parameters, also include the time window to each date.
- Step 3: join all together to see what dates have user in that time window
- Step 4: select only user with a time window for all dates

[image]

Comment: The first case its working but not the second one.

If I search from 2016-09-01 08:00:00 to 2016-09-04 17:00:00 I get 3 result with user 1 but should only get 1. 

User 1 is only available on 2016-09-03 from 08:00:00 to 17:00:00.

Comment: I only answer the first part, the second require a lot of work isnt really trivial. You need split the range into multiple dates